# Is there a CAPL function to access the hardware configuration?

Tags: capl, canoe

I am setting up a test environment using CANoe.  Depending on the test that I want to run, I need to configure properly the hardware just before running the test.

I was able to use the panel to configure the hardware and export the settings for later import, but I am not able to launch this from the test itself, therefore there is a manual action that is required before the tests attached to different HW configuration are enabled.

I would like to be able to restore the HW configuration directly from the test (CAPL).

Answer (score 1):

*Depending* on what kind of hardware you are using (VNs, CANCards,Flexray,CAN, Ethernet, LIN,etc) you have or you have not access to such settings.

For example, for CAN-FD you have the **canFdGetConfiguration**(), **canFdSetConfiguration()**, and for CAN **canGetConfiguration**().

You also have a similar access for FlexRay network also: **frGetConfiguration()**.

Hit the F1 on these, and the Help will explain their usage.